# Question on Gambler's Ruin

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes

Adam and Bob bet on the outcomes of coin tosses. $P(H)=p$ and $P(T)=1-p=q.$

Adam wins \$1 from Bob if it shows heads and Bob wins \$1 from Adam if it shows 
tails. Adam begins with \$ $k$ and Bob \$ $(N-k)$. The game is over as soon as 
one of them runs out of money. What is the probability that Adam wins all? 
Hint: Consider when the first toss is heads and when it is not heads.

So, given that $P_k$ is the probability that Adam wins all given that he begins 
with \$$k$, I started off with:

$$P_k=P(A_k|H)P(H)+P(A_k|H^c)P(H^c)=P_{k+1}\cdot p + P_{k-1}\cdot q$$
$$(p+q)P_k=pP_{k+1}+qP_{k-1}$$
$$p(P_{k+1}-P_k)=q(P_k-P_{k-1})$$

but I can't proceed onwards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider a game with fixed total stake `n`.

If Adam starts with `a` dollars and the first toss is heads, his 
chance of winning is the same as if he started with `a+1` dollars. If 
the first toss is tails, his chance of winning is the same as if he 
started with `a-1` dollars. Since the chance of heads is `p` and the 
chance of tails is `1-p`, Adam's overall probability of winning with 
$a$, $r(a)$, is:

$r(a)=(1-p) r(a-1)+p r(a+1)$

The recursion looks ugly this way, so let's solve for $r(a+1)$:

$r(a+1)=\frac{(p-1) r(a-1)+r(a)}{p}$

We also know that $r(0)=0$ and that $r(n)=1$. I think this might've 
been the step you were missing: the boundary conditions.

Solving this recurrence, we find:

$r(a)=\frac{\left(\frac{1}{p}-1\right)^a-1}{\left(\frac{1}{p}-1\right)^n-1}$